# Is a custom usercontrol created each time the datacontext changes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

This is more of a general question...
I have a user control that i've written (UserControl,not Custom Control). i'm using this control in the a DataGridColumn to provide lookup functionality..much like this:

```
                <DataGridTemplate ColumnHeader="Company">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <lookupCtl:LookUpCTL SelectedCompany="{Binding Company, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                           CompanyChangedCommand="{Binding DataContext.CompanyChangedCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

What i'm noticing is that whenever the dataconext changes for the parent/containing control, the constructor of LookUpCTL is called.  Is this expected behavior?  Anyway to prevent this? as i don't see why this necessary...the single instance of the control should be able to refresh itself from the datacontext i think.

Edit: googling is not providing any clear answers...but from what i've read, it may be the Datagrid that's the issue.  since my control is used in a datagrid, each time the grid's itemsource changes, does it destroy and recreate the controls?  i can see sense in it doing so..but not sure if that is the reason for what i'm seeing.  Assuming it is...is there a way to have the datagrid reuse instances of the usercontrol rather than create new ones when the datagrid's itemsource changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear that the reason usercontrols used as DataTemplate columns for a datagrid are destroyed and recreated when the itemsource for the datagrid is changed.  in my case the solution was to use a normal grid given that i had always 4 items in my list that was used as the itemsource for the grid.  This is not ideal and not a solution for N-item lists..but in my case it vastly improved performance since my usercontrol performed some intensive datbase lookups on initialization to cache data.

Comment: getting data from database and caching it is not a responsiblity of the view. This looks like the kind of hacks normally found in winforms. If you had a proper architecture you wouldn't have the need to resort to that, because the usercontrols actually wouldn't need to do anything when created.

Comment: helpful..blame the architecure from 5 lines of xaml. the control allows consumers to supply the data through adapters/providers. it renders the data using hierarchical templates to group them up to 4 levels deep.  its fairly efficient at it given the size of the data.  the control is not the problem. it's the template that uses these controls.  when a user selects from a master list, the itemssource of the datagrid changes. since the ctl is template column of the data grid, it's recreated.  that's the problem.  have you a solution? or just broad criticism from 5 lines of xaml?

Comment: I don't care if you build up an entire Explorer.exe Windows shell inside a user control, Still, getting data from database and caching it is not the responsibility of the View. Ever heard of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)? its a fairly new concept, so I understand if you never heard of it before. It's been around since 1975 or something.

Comment: seriously, if you have nothing to contribute..there is no need to comment.  StackOverflow is not a forum to make yourself feel better by trolling for questions to compensate from some sort of inferiority complex.  your SOC comment doesn't warrant a response since you still can't seem to understand the control does not do any fetching of data..it's provided data...wether its from a database, a webservice, a flat file, etc.  it's job is to render that data...i guess maybe you should not just post links, but read them as well.